# Pyspark: using udf within window

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, time-series, user-defined-functions, apache-spark-sql

I need to detect threshold values on timeseries with Pyspark.
On the example graph below I want to detect (by storing the associated timestamp) each occurrence of the parameter ALT_STD being larger than 5000 and then lower than 5000.

[image: ALT_STD vs Time]

For this simple case I can run simple queries such as

```python
t_start = df.select('timestamp')\
                .filter(df.ALT_STD > 5000)\
                .sort('timestamp')\
                .first()
t_stop = df.select('timestamp')\
               .filter((df.ALT_STD < 5000)\                           
                       & (df.timestamp > t_start.timestamp))\
               .sort('timestamp')\
               .first()
```

However, in some cases, the event can by cyclic and I may have several curves (i.e. several times ALT_STD will raise above or below 5000). Of course, if I use the queries above I will only be able to detect the first occurrences.

I guess I should use window function with an udf, but I can't find a working solution.
My guess is that the algorithm should be something like:

```python
windowSpec = Window.partitionBy('flight_hash')\
                   .orderBy('timestamp')\
                   .rowsBetween(Window.currentRow, 1)

def detect_thresholds(x):
    if (x['ALT_STD'][current_row]< 5000) and (x['ALT_STD'][next_row] > 5000):
        return x['timestamp'] #Or maybe simply 1
    if (x['ALT_STD'][current_row]> 5000) and (x['ALT_STD'][current_row] > 5000):
    return x['timestamp'] #Or maybe simply 2
    else:
        return 0

import pyspark.sql.functions as F
detect_udf = F.udf(detect_threshold, IntegerType())
df.withColumn('Result', detect_udf(F.Struct('ALT_STD')).over(windowSpec).show()
```

Is such an algorithm feasible in Pyspark ? How ?

*Post-scriptum:*
As a side note, I have understood how to use udf or udf and built-in sql window functions but not how to combine udf AND window.
e.g. :

```python
# This will compute the mean (built-in function)
df.withColumn("Result", F.mean(df['ALT_STD']).over(windowSpec)).show()

# This will also work
divide_udf = F.udf(lambda x: x[0]/1000., DoubleType())
df.withColumn('result', divide_udf(F.struct('timestamp')))
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for udf here (and python udfs cannot be used as window functions). Just use `lead` / `lag` with `when`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lag, lead, when

result = (when((col('ALT_STD') < 5000) & (lead(col('ALT_STD'), 1) > 5000), 1)
    .when(col('ALT_STD') > 5000) & (lead(col('ALT_STD'), 1) < 5000), 1)
    .otherwise(0))

df.withColum("result", result)
```

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. However I get an error when running this code : Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o18780.showString.
: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot evaluate expression: lead(input[2, bigint, true], 1, null)

Comment: Also, lag is imported but not used in your example, is this a mistake ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to user9569772 answer I found out. His solution did not work because .lag() or .lead() are window functions.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# Define conditions
det_start = (F.lag(F.col('ALT_STD')).over(windowSpec) < 100)\
          & (F.lead(F.col('ALT_STD'), 0).over(windowSpec) >= 100)
det_end = (F.lag(F.col('ALT_STD'), 0).over(windowSpec) > 100)\
        & (F.lead(F.col('ALT_STD')).over(windowSpec) < 100)

# Combine conditions with .when() and .otherwise()
result = (when(det_start, 1)\
       .when(det_end, 2)\
       .otherwise(0))

df.withColumn("phases", result).show()
```